# how do i pass scope from controller to service in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
'use strict';

  /* Controllers */

  angular.module('stocks.controllers', []).
    controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$http', 'stockData', function MyCtrl1 ($scope, $http, stockData) {

        $scope.submit = function() {




        $scope.info = stockData.query();
        console.dir($scope.info);
        }

    }]);
```

and i want to pass a bound ng-model that sits in my view called `ng-model="symbol_wanted"` to the following service...

```
'use strict';

    /* Services */

    angular.module('stocks.services', ['ngResource']).factory('stockData', ['$resource',
      function($resource){
        return $resource('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
      });
    }]);
```

how do i connect the controller's scope to get passed into the service? thanks!

Comment: when?  Have you defined a function to be called on an `ng-click`?

Comment: The question is strange, as it assumes you can't just do: `myService($scope)`. The rest of comments and answers are showing different `angularjs` patterns instead of answering what is asked in the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> how do i pass scope from controller to service in angularjs?

You can't inject $scope into services, there is no such thing as a Singleton $scope.

> i want to pass a bound ng-model that sits in my view called ng-model="symbol_wanted" to the following service...

You can call the service and pass parameters this way:

```
    .factory('stockData', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {

    var factory = {
        query: function (value) {

            // here you can play with 'value'

            var data = $resource('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22YHOO%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: false
                }
            });
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

So we call this service and get a promise back like this:

```
 stockData.query(value) // <-- pass value
        .then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result;            
    }, function (result) {
        alert("Error: No data returned");
    });
```

BTW, I'd suggest you use `$http.get`:

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/694/)

Comment: i did this and i get Error: $scope is not defined. how do i access $scope.symbol_wanted in the controller?

Comment: in controller or service? from your example `$scope` is defined

Comment: i implemented your code, and its not alerting or setting off errors in the console tab, but i don't see any data coming back from the ajax call.

Comment: i also added $q next to $resource in the controller.

Comment: also the value is passing as it should.

Comment: Maxim why do you recommend to use $http instead of a resource ?

Comment: @Tamy Generally its two diff things and it bases on your goals. The `$http` you can configure `POST` `GET` and it works like ajax request as we know from jQuery. For `$resource` you can configure request to get specific data based on parameters we pass. For example if on server side we have json object and I dont want to get full json but one object with id=7 for example. So I can configure $resource to get only object with id 7 automatically with no logic on server side.

Comment: @Tamy Forgot main thing:  for `resource` should be RESTful server-side data sources

Answer (score 4):

Your `ng-model` value will automatically become a scope property.  So, you can just use this in your controller to get the current value:

```
$scope.symbol_wanted;
```

So, let's say that you have a function to handle the click in your controller:

```
$scope.handleMyClick = function() {

    stockData.query($scope.symbol_wanted);
}
```

You can just use the scoped property.

Comment: i did this and i get Error: $scope is not defined. how do i access $scope.symbol_wanted in the controller?

Comment: In your example above, you are already using `$scope` in your controller.  My example is meant to go into the controller as well.

Comment: You are going to have to also add your html markup so we can see how `ng-model` is defined.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Am I missing something?