# Angular JS - Receiving information from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a controller and service pair that are functioning properly right now, but my boss wants me to move the success/error/finally blocks from the controller to the service.

Controller Function:

```
            $scope.createUserButton = function () {
                $scope.isBusy = true;
                creationService.makeNewUser($scope.form)
                .success(function (data) {
                    var user = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (typeof user !== 'undefined') {
                        $scope.testusers.push(user);
                    }

                }).error(function () {
                    notify({
                        message: 'Could not create user',
                        classes: 'alert-danger',
                        templateUrl: 'partials/settingNotification.html'
                    });
                }).finally(function () {
                    $scope.isBusy = false;
                });
            };
```

Service:

```
service('creationService', ['restfulRepo', '$http',
function (restfulRepo, $http) {
this.makeNewUser = function (tempuser) {
    return $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:60098/***/*************/******',
        data: tempuser, method: 'PUT'
    });
};
}]);
```

The problem that I'm having is that if I move the success or finally blocks to the service, then they don't have access to the isBusy flag or to the testusers array. The array is bound to a graph in the controller that displays the information handed back.

Comment: `$http` returns a promise, in your controller you can do this: `creationService. makeNewUser().then(function(){ $scope.isBusy = false; });`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#!/  "The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to `false` then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my response, you can let data binding alleviate that for you. Notice how we set the controller & service isBusy variables.

Controller:

```
$scope.isBusy = creationService.isBusy; //1-way Data Binding
$scope.createUserButton = function () {
            creationService.isBusy = true;
            creationService.makeNewUser($scope.form).then(
                    function(user){
                       $scope.testusers.push(user);
                    }, function(error){
                       notify({
                       message: error,
                       classes: 'alert-danger',
                       templateUrl: 'partials/settingNotification.html'
                       });
                    });

        };
```

Service:

```
service('creationService', ['restfulRepo', '$http', '$q', function (restfulRepo, $http, $q) {
this.isBusy = false;

this.makeNewUser = function (tempuser) {
var defer = $q.defer();
  $http({
    url: 'http://localhost:60098/***/*************/******',
    data: tempuser, method: 'PUT'
  }).success(function (data) {
                var user = JSON.parse(data);
                if (typeof user !== 'undefined') {
                    defer.resolve(user);
                }else{
                   defer.reject("Undefined user");
                }
            }).error(function () {
                defer.reject('Could not create user');
            }).finally(function () {
                this.isBusy = false;
            });
     return defer.promise;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I had to make some slight changes. Thank you
`var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:60098/api/createTestUsers/createUser',
            data: tempuser, method: 'PUT'
        }).success(function (data) {
            var user = JSON.parse(data);
            defer.resolve(user);
        }).error(function () {
            notify({
                message: 'Could not create user',
                classes: 'alert-danger',
                templateUrl: 'partials/settingNotification.html'
            });
        });
        return defer.promise;`

Comment: My absolute pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what responsibilities the service has. This is an example if you consider your service just as a way to talk to a server.

And the controller is responsible of just getting the data from the service and doing something with it like binding it to the view or showing an error message.

**Service:**

```
service('creationService', ['restfulRepo', '$http',
    function (restfulRepo, $http) {
        this.makeNewUser = function (tempuser) {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:60098/***/*************/******',
                data: tempuser, method: 'PUT'
            }).then(function(){
                var user = JSON.parse(data);
                return user;
            }, function(e){
                //check server error response e to send the correct object to the controller
                throw {
                    message: 'Could not create user',
                    classes: 'alert-danger',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/settingNotification.html'
                };
            });
        };
    }]);
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.createUserButton = function () {
    $scope.isBusy = true;
    creationService.makeNewUser($scope.form)
        .then(function (user) {
            if (typeof user !== 'undefined') {
                $scope.testusers.push(user);
            }
        }, function (e) {
            notify(e);
        })
        .finally(function () {
            $scope.isBusy = false;
        });
};
```

Comment: wrapping `$http` inside a `deferred` is an anti-pattern, since `$http` already returns a promise.

Comment: @Claies that is so true. Let me change it.

Comment: @Claies I changed the answer to return the promise.

Answer (score 0):

Related: [Injecting $scope into an angular service function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898927/injecting-scope-into-an-angular-service-function)

[how do i pass scope from controller to service in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747830/how-do-i-pass-scope-from-controller-to-service-in-angularjs)

It might be best for you to just move both your data `testusers` and the `isBusy` boolean to the service. This way all your other controllers can access `testusers` and be controlled by the `isBusy` variable.

**Service**

```
service('creationService', ['restfulRepo', '$http',
function (restfulRepo, $http) {
this.testusers = []; // do whatever you want with it
this.isBusy = false;
this.makeNewUser = function (tempuser) {
    return $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:60098/***/*************/******',
        data: tempuser, method: 'PUT'
    });
};
this.toggleBusy = function(){
    this.isBusy = this.isBusy ? false : true;
};
this.createUserErr = function () {
                notify({
                    message: 'Could not create user',
                    classes: 'alert-danger',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/settingNotification.html'
                };
this.createUserSuc = function (data) {
                var user = JSON.parse(data);
                if (typeof user !== 'undefined') {
                    this.testusers.push(user);
                }

            }

}]);
```

**Controller**

```
        $scope.createUserButton = function () {
            creationService.toggleBusy();
            creationService.makeNewUser(creationService.createUserSuc)
            .success().error(creationService.createUserErr);
            }).finally(creationService.toggleBusy);
        };
```