# Angular - Use scope Variable in Service url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Currently I'd like to get data from an API, sending some search parameters using an AngularJS service. In my ng-model I have a variable called search, and I would like to use that variable as a parameter to the API URL.

My first (unsuccessful) approach was to use the $scope.search variable directly inside the service:

```js
$http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+ $scope.search +'&type=series&r=json').then(function(data){
     deferred.resolve(data);
});
```

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747830/how-do-i-pass-scope-from-controller-to-service-in-angularjs) that passing the $scope to the service is not possible (and shouldn't be done anyway), so how can I use the scope variable as a parameter in the service, also, is there a cleaner way to set the paramaters other than adding the string `myUrl + search`?

full code:

```js
 myApp.service('showsService', function($http, $q){
    var deferred = $q.defer(); //promise to say 'im going to do this later'
    $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=sherlock&type=series&r=json').then(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    this.getShows = function(){
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    });

    myApp.controller("showsController", function($scope, showsService){
    $scope.$watch('search', function() {
      fetch();
    });

    function fetch(){
        var promise = showsService.getShows();
        promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.showsResult = data.data.Search; //using the name than comes back from the API
    });
    }
    });
```

Comment: the answer to your question is in the other question you referenced.  Did you try implementing the solution provided there before asking essentially the same question again?

Comment: in the given solution they don't use the `http.get` function which i'm using, neither do they use a service -as far as I can see- since they implement a factory?

Comment: the concept is still the same, but your code is all wrong here anyway.  You are trying to call the `$http.get` when the service is initialized (app startup), and since services are singletons, it's only ever going to make the call once.  also, `$http` returns a promise, so you shouldn't wrap that promise inside another promise (don't use `$q` here).  pass your parameter to your `getShows(searchTerm)`, call your `$http.get` *inside* that function, and return that, to chain `.then()` from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass `search` as an argument to the service function:

```
myApp.service('showsService', function($http){
    this.getShows = function(search){
        var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/s='+search+'&type=series&r=json';
        var promise = $http.get(url);
        return promise;
    };
});
```

Then in the controller:

```
myApp.controller("showsController", function($scope, showsService){
   $scope.$watch('search', function(value) {
      fetch(value);
   });

   function fetch(search){
       var promise = showsService.getShows(search);
       promise.then(function(response){
           $scope.showsResult = response.data.Search;
       });
    };
});
```

There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer` as the `$http` service already returns a promise.

---

### Update

The `$http` service is able to serialize parameters:

```
myApp.service('showsService', function($http){
    this.getShows = function(search){
        //var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/s='+search+'&type=series&r=json';
        var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/'
        var config = { 
            params: { 
                s: search,
                type: 'series',
                r: 'json'
            }
        };
        var promise = $http.get(url, config);
        return promise;
    };
});
```

Comment: Please use the `$http` `params` config object ~ `$http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com', { params: { s: search, type: 'series', r: 'json' } })`. Concatenating strings into URL query parameters is not safe

Comment: great, thanks! i got the idea of using the `$q.defer` from a video tutorial on youtube, but now i understand better the use of $http, cheers!. I will also try to use the `params` config object as suggested by @Phil

Comment: These Angular tutorials remind me of all the terrible PHP tutorials and all the damage they did

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the search data to service

```
var getShows = showsService.getShows($scope.search);
getShows.then(function(resposne){
    console.log(resposne.data);
})
```

Service code

```
myApp.service('showsService',['$http',function commonSrv($http) {
this.getShows=function(search)
      {
        var promise = $http({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/',
          data:{"s":search, 'type':'series'},
          contentType:'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        });
        return promise;
      };
}]);
```